# Hold bool while animating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, animator

I am an 3d artist and I have a hard time understanding programming, but I am trying.

For more than a week now I have not been able to find a simple solution to how to freeze the bool while the attack animation is playing. Since I am using the "Update", pressing the "fire1" switches the bool for a very short time, and I need it to work until the attack animation ends.

Thanks!

[Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5BuB.jpg)

```
void Update () {
    
    // WASD
    
    float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    Vector3 move = Quaternion.Euler (0, playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
    
    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        animator.SetBool("Walk", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
        
    }
    
    // Attack
    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        playerSpeed = 0f;
        
    
        animator.SetBool("Attack", true);
        animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
        
        
    }
    else 
    {
        playerSpeed = 2f;
        animator.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }    
    }
```

Comment: Why? Why don't you rather simply configure your transition from `Attack` to `Idle` to only happen time based once the attack animation finished and not depend on the `Attack` bool ?

Comment: And we'll in general `Input.GetButtonDown` is `true` only in the one single frame where the key was pressed down .. your `else` block is executed in all other frames and resets the bool parameter ...

Comment: The animations work as expected, the point is to prevent the character from moving during the attack.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here as you understood is that the Input.GetkeyDown("Fire1") returns true a single frame after you pressed the button then becomes false and therefore switches off the attack animation.

I think you could use the animator and its built-in features to make a transition to the idle/walk animation after a set timer (I think this is what you're looking for). Like this : [The Attack Animation Transition after 1 second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lei3.jpg)

The idle animation transitions to the attack animation with the attack bool : [Idle Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRm7K.jpg), same for the walk animation

For the code, since you want to change the player's speed when you trigger and remove the attack animation it's pretty easy:

```
void Update () {

// WASD

float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 move = Quaternion.Euler (0, playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

if (move != Vector3.zero)
{
    gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    animator.SetBool("Walk", true);
}
else 
{
    animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
}

// Attack
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    playerSpeed = 0f;
    animator.SetBool("Attack", true));
    //We don't need to set the walk bool off so that we directly transiton 
    //to the walk animation or the idle animation after  the attack
}
else
{
   animator.SetBool("Attack", false);
}

//if we're not on the attack animation, the animation 
//transitions by itself with the animator transitions
if(!animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack"))
{
    playerSpeed = 2f;
}    
}
```

Tell me if I made an error on the code or you need more help. Have a good one!

Comment: The problem is not that the animation of the attack is interrupted, but that during the animation of the attack, the character can move, for this I need bool "Walk" and "Attaсk".When the player attacks, the variable becomes true, and the character cannot move, but since it switches in 1 frame, it does not work as it should.

Comment: Well I made sure that when you trigger the attack, in the `Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")`, it puts your playerSpeed at 0, and when your attack animation stops  which means `(!animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack"))` it restarts again.
Your attack and walk bools are unnecessary since the animator can already tell you at which state you are using the animator.GetCurrenrAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Name") and then change your speed accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it definitely makes the code cleaner, but how can you prevent the player from moving when he attacks?